# How to determine the joint density with shared random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

Consider we have three random variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ that are jointly multivariate normal. Assume also a bijective function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

How may I compute the joint density of $(y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4)$ given that:
\begin{align}
 (y_1, y_2) &= f(x_1, x_2) \,\, \text{ and}\\
 (y_3, y_4) &= f(x_2, x_3)
\end{align}

First thought was that I could define joint density of $(x_1, x_2, x_2, x_3)$ and then use the formula for transforming probability densities as per usual with the Jacobian etc,,, but this doesn't seem appropriate as the above vector has $x_2$ repeated and, I believe, it's not possible to define a density for a random variable with itself given it would have measure zero?

Second idea was to instead to consider the multivariate normal distribution of the three random variables $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ which is clearly well defined, but in that case I would not be able to compute the Jacobian as I would have to define an appropriate new function $\bar{f}:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ and such jacobian would not be square. Does the joint density that I'm looking for exist and how can I derive it?

Comment: You can start from the expression $\int G(x_1,x_2,x_3)\delta(f(x_1,x_2)-a)\delta(f(x_2,x_3)-b)dx_1dx_2dx_3$, where $G$ is the joint gaussian

Comment: Could you shed a bit more light? I am not sure what $a$ and $b$ are and why this should work? Happy to give it a go, just not very experienced with these things so not seeing immediately what the delta functions do.

Comment: Is that just to derive the CDF? If so, that doesnt guarantee that the pdf exists though?

Comment: Sorry, $f$ is a vector. Then what I mean is $\int G(x_1,x_2,x_3)\delta(y_1(x_1,x_2)-a_1)\delta(y_2(x_1,x_2)-a_2)\delta(y_3(x_2,x_3)-a_3)\delta(y_4(x_2,x_3)-a_4)dx_1dx_2dx_3$. This will be the joint probability distribution that $y_1=a_1,y_2=a_2,y_3=a_3,y_4=a_4$. The integration takes into account all possibilities for the variables $x$, and the delta functions select those of interest to you, that is kind of the rationale.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense to me, so I suppose another way of writing would be $\delta(y_1 - f_1(x_1, x_2))$ etc. This would give me the pdf, I can see now,, will give it a go thanks